# Feynman rules Horndeski theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, modified-gravity

Let $\phi$ be a scalar field and $g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu}+h_{\mu \nu}/M_p$ where $M_p$ is the Planck mass (so we assume we deal with perturbations). Let $\Lambda_2,\Lambda_3$ be energy scales such that $\Lambda_2 \gg \Lambda_3$. These are defined by $\Lambda^2_2 = M_p H_0$ and $\Lambda_3^3 = M_p H_0^2$. The [Horndeski action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horndeski%27s_theory) is:

$$S = \int d^4 x \sqrt{-g} \sum^5_{i=2} \mathcal{L}_i,$$

where

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L_2}&=\Lambda_2^4 G_2,\nonumber \\
\mathcal{L_3}&=\Lambda_2^4 G_3 [\Phi], \nonumber \\
\mathcal{L_4}&= M_p^2 G_4 R + \Lambda_2^4 G_{4,X}([\Phi]^2 - [\Phi^2]),\nonumber \\
\mathcal{L_5}&= M_p^2 G_5 G_{\mu \nu}\Phi^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{6}\Lambda_2^4 G_{5,X}([\Phi]^3 - 3[\Phi][\Phi^2] + 2[\Phi^3]), \nonumber
\end{align}

where $G_2,G_3,G_4,G_5$ are functions of $\phi$ and $X = -\frac{1}{2}\nabla^\mu \phi \nabla_\mu \phi /\Lambda_2^4$, $\Phi^{\mu}_{ \ \nu}:= \nabla^\mu \nabla_\nu \phi/\Lambda_3^3$ and square brackets indicate the trace, e.g. $[\Phi^2] = \nabla^\mu \nabla_\nu \phi \nabla^\nu \nabla_\mu \phi/\Lambda_3^6$ and $,$ denote partial derivatives.

In the paper [arXiv:1904.05874](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.05874) they state the Feynman rules in the Appendix. In the paper they try to derive the Feynman rules from the above action around the vacuum expectation value $\langle \phi \rangle = 0$. It says for instance that the leading-order vertex for $\phi\phi\phi$ is given by:

$$-\frac{\bar{G}_{3,X} + 3\bar{G}_{4,\phi X}}{3\Lambda_3^3}\delta^{\mu \nu}_{\alpha \beta}\phi \phi^\nu_\mu \phi^\beta_\alpha,$$

where the bar indicates that the function is evaluated at $\langle \phi \rangle = 0$, $\delta$ is the generalized Kronecker delta and $\phi^\nu_\mu:= \nabla^\nu \nabla_\mu \phi$.

My question is how can I derive such an expression from the action?

Comment: As a hint, write $\phi = \bar\Phi + \varphi$ where $\langle \phi \rangle = \bar\Phi$, expand the action to cubic order in $\varphi$, and use the normal rules given in a QFT book to derive the cubic $\varphi$ vertex (for example, you can differentiate the partition function $Z[J]$ wrt $J$, where the path integral measure is $D\varphi$ as opposed to $D\phi$).

Comment: @Andrew, could you please elaborate a bit on how differentiation of $Z[J]$ w.r.t. $J$ leads to the Feynman rules? (Just for clarity this is not a homework question but for my research I need to understand the derivations of the paper to proceed on the work in this paper.)

Comment: It's covered in every QFT book; a good free resource are Srednicki's lecture notes http://www.cns.gatech.edu/FieldTheory/extras/SrednickiQFT03.pdf, see chapter 10.

Comment: Then $\phi=\varphi$ since $<\phi>=0$?. And with expanding to cubic order in $\varphi$ you do not mean also expanding in $X$ right? Since $X$ is not necessarily small if $\varphi$ is small

Comment: It's true that $\phi=\varphi$ but you shouldn't assume this for derivatives, $\partial \phi = \partial \Phi + \partial \varphi \neq \partial \varphi$. So $X \sim (\partial \Phi)^2 + 2 \partial \Phi \partial \varphi + (\partial \varphi)^2$.

Comment: @Andrew, excuse me but this still does not make sense to me at all. Since if $\phi = \varphi$ then it is immediate that $\partial \phi = \partial \varphi$. Could you please show how the functions $G_{i}(X,\phi)$ are expanded and give some steps without working them out in detail so that I can proceed with it?

Comment: It's not the case that $\phi=\varphi$.... Rather, $\phi=\bar\Phi + \varphi$. The key point is that you have to be careful about the ordering of two operations: 1. Taking derivatives and 2. plugging in values. You must do 1 before 2. So first expand $\mathcal{L}$ to second order in $\varphi$, without assuming $\bar\Phi$ is zero. You will get a bunch of terms that depend on derivatives of $G$ coming from the Taylor expansion. *Then* set $\bar\Phi=0$. When you do this you shouldn't assume the derivatives of $G$ vanish.

Comment: For example, if $G=a \phi (\partial \phi)^2 = a \phi X$, then after this process $G =a\varphi (\partial \varphi)^2$. In more general notation, $\bar{G}_{\phi X} = a$. So you can also write this example as $\bar{G}_{\phi X} \varphi (\partial \varphi)^2$.

Comment: So should I write the following? $\phi = \Phi + \varphi$ such that e.g. $G_2(X,\phi) = \sum_{n,m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!n!} \frac{\partial^{n+m}}{\partial \phi^m \partial X^n}G_2(X,\phi)\Big|_{\phi = \Phi, X = 0} \varphi^m X^n$ where $X = -\frac{1}{2} \nabla_\mu \varphi \nabla^\mu \varphi$ in general ?

Comment: I mean, there's no reason to do an infinite series if you're only going to second order, but yes. And you should be careful to distinguish $X=(\partial \bar\Phi)^2$ from (making up a symbol) $Y=(\partial \varphi)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to summarize some discussion in the comments, since comments get deleted and it ended up building up to half an answer.

Let's take a simple example, $G=-\frac{1}{2} a \phi (\partial \phi)^2 = a \phi X$, where $X\equiv -\frac{1}{2} (\partial \phi)^2$. Then we perturb $\phi$
\begin{equation}
\phi = \bar\Phi + \varphi
\end{equation}
**Even though we will ultimately set $\langle \phi \rangle = \bar\Phi = 0$, we do not want to do this yet.** First, we expand the Lagrangian; in our example this is $G$
\begin{equation}
G = a \left(\bar\Phi \bar X - \bar\Phi \partial_\mu \bar \Phi \partial^\mu \varphi + \bar\Phi Y + \varphi \bar X - \varphi \partial_\mu \bar \Phi \partial^\mu \varphi + \varphi Y \right)
\end{equation}
where I've defined $\bar{X} = - \frac{1}{2} (\partial \bar\Phi)^2 $ and $Y = -\frac{1}{2} (\partial \varphi)^2$.

**Now we set $\bar\Phi = \bar X = 0$.** Then our example reduces to
\begin{equation}
G = a \varphi Y
\end{equation}
Since $G_{\phi X}(\phi=\bar\Phi=0, X=\bar X=0) = a$, we can equivalently write this as
\begin{equation}
G = \bar{G}_{\phi X} \varphi Y
\end{equation}

To get the Feynman rules from the Lagrangian for $\varphi$, one then follows one of the normal procedures, for example differentiating the partition function, as described in many sources. An example source that is free is Chapter 10 of Srednicki's lecture notes of QFT (and the preceding chapters which set the stage for chapter 10): cns.gatech.edu/FieldTheory/extras/SrednickiQFT03.pdf. In the case of this example, there will be a cubic vertex with an associated factor of something like $i \bar{G}_{\phi X} k^2$ (I am not 100% sure about the factor of $i$... I think you get a $-i$ from the definition of the amplitude, $-1/2$ from the definition of $Y$, and $2$ from the fact that the two legs with $\partial \phi$ are identical... but this should be checked carefully)